# Javascript function inside called in loop

Tags: javascript

Good day,
I found a sweet little javascript that suits my needs but I want to call this function many times on the same page. It is my understanding that for each call to the function needs to be defined with a unique id.

I would put this in a loop like this end like this

```
<td><div id='countdown$i'></div></td>
```

Here is the loop

```
    $i=0;
    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if ($time < $endtime) {
        echo "<script>
        var interval;
        var minutes = 1;
        var seconds = 10;
        window.onload = function() {
            countdown('countdown');
        }

        function countdown(element) {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                var el = document.getElementById(element);
                    if(seconds == 0) {
                    if(minutes == 0) {
                    location.reload(true);
                    } else {
                        minutes--;
                        seconds = 60;
                    }
                }
                if(minutes > 0) {
                    var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' min(s)' : ' min');
                    var secound_text = '';
                    el.innerHTML = 'Ready in ' + minute_text;
                } else {
                    var minute_text = '';
                    var second_text = seconds + (seconds > 1 ? ' sec(s)' : ' sec');
                    el.innerHTML = 'Ready in ' + second_text;
                }
                seconds--;
            }, 1000);
        }
        </script>";
        echo "<td width='200'><div id='countdown$i'></div></td>";
        $i++;
    }
```

What/where should i modify the script to repond to countdown$i ?

Thanks

Comment: No, **do not** put the function in a PHP loop and output it several times, just make it indepedent of the DOM and call it as many times as you want.

Comment: @adeneo 
Thanks for the quick reply.
I removed the fonction from COM and added it too the header.  Now when calling the fonction in the loop only the last iteration gives results. 
What should i be looking into ? Should i still call it this way ? id='countdown$i'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing it this way; however, this should fix your code.

```
window.onload = function() {
        countdown('countdown".$i."');
    }
```